# Difference between SQL variable datatype and Table column datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, types

What is the difference between SQL `variable` datatype and Table `column` datatype.

Consider the below example:

```
DECLARE @variable CHAR(1)

SET @variable = 'quarter'

SELECT @variable --works
```

Result: `Q`

But when I do the same in Table am getting error

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
  (
     col CHAR(1)
  )

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES      ('quarter') --Fails
```

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 9 String or binary data would be
>   truncated.

I went through MSDN about [DECLARE @local_variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188927.aspx) still didn't get any answer. Can anyone tell me what is the reason.

Comment: there is no difference in types, but in operators (set vs insert)

Comment: @Lashane -Thanks, Can you explain in detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the main difference is how warnings in `SET` vs `INSERT` work, here is [SET ANSI_WARNINGS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx)

> When set to ON, the divide-by-zero and arithmetic overflow errors cause the statement to be rolled back and an error message is generated. When set to OFF, the divide-by-zero and arithmetic overflow errors cause null values to be returned. The behavior in which a divide-by-zero or arithmetic overflow error causes null values to be returned occurs `if an INSERT or UPDATE is tried on a character, Unicode, or binary column in which the length of a new value exceeds the maximum size of the column. If SET ANSI_WARNINGS is ON, the INSERT or UPDATE is canceled as specified by the ISO standard.` Trailing blanks are ignored for character columns and trailing nulls are ignored for binary columns. When OFF, data is truncated to the size of the column and the statement succeeds.

but, it does not affect SET statements:

> ANSI_WARNINGS is not honored when passing parameters in a stored procedure, user-defined function, or when declaring and `setting variables` in a batch statement. For example, `if a variable is defined as char(3), and then set to a value larger than three characters, the data is truncated to the defined size` and the INSERT or UPDATE statement succeeds.

so, you could disable ansi warnings and your insert query will work. But I'd prefer to have warnings on, but do data validation/truncation on app side.

Comment: +1 This is a fine answer, but from a practice standpoint, it would be bad to do that in my opinion. The correct thing would be to substring/left the field when inserting it.

Comment: @Ghost I see nothing wrong with having an _option_ to do one or the other.  Can you honestly say that in _every single situation_ that truncating silently is the "right" thing to do?  If anything I would say _consistency_ between `SET` and `INSERT` (while maintaining optionality) would be better.

Comment: @DStanley I maintain that in every single situation it would be better for the code to explicitly truncate the data than an option that implicitly truncates the data.

Comment: @Ghost Well, I maintain that there may be times where you want a potential truncation to be an _error_, so I see optionality as a good thing.  But I guess we have to agree to disagree.